# Strange issue with shadows in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

For some inexplainable reason, the shadows on my object are showing up very strangely. Everything showed up correctly until I restarted Blender. I did not change anything to my knowledge before closing. Older autosaves have the issue as well. Maybe there is a global setting I changed by mistake?

Edit: Both viewports are set to rendered.

[image: Before; no bizarre shadows]
*Before*

[image: After; weird shadows]
*After*

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the first has viewport shading set to rendered and the second is in look dev.

Comment: @rjg Both viewports are set to rendered.

Comment: check your normal maps